# Solve the trig system of equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

This is a repost, I'm new here and I did a terrible job explaining the question last time.
I'm trying to make an IK system, the rig basicly works in 2d with the bones shown below.
[(Rig in Unreal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyqsx.jpg)

The map of the Bones is as [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCLj6.jpg).

^[Original on paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4MQU.jpg)

a, b, c, x, & y are known I need to solve for $\alpha$ and $\theta$

The equations I have right now are:

$ x = a\cos(\theta)-b\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha+\theta)+c\cos(\theta)$

$y = -(a\sin(\theta)+b\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha+\theta)+c\sin(\theta)) $

The equations can be simplified (thanks to [Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue))

$d := a + c$

$\phi := \alpha-\theta$

$ x = d\cos\theta-b\cos\phi$

$ y = d\sin\theta+b\sin\phi$

$\alpha = \theta+\phi$

With this method you have to solve for $\phi$ and $\theta$

I have tried a lot of different ways to solve for $\phi$ but all of them end with me getting stuck and or it becomes unequal (making them useless).

Edit: thanks for all the support, I didn't think anyone would answer, but I typed in the equations wrong, I forget the "a"s at the beginning and the - on the y. I guess that's what waking up does. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method.

$x^2 + y^2 = $

$d^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) + b^2(\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi) - 2db (\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta\sin\phi) = $

$ d^2 + b^2 - 2db\cos(\theta + \phi)$

You said that you know $x, y, d$ and $b$. Therefore, $\cos(\theta + \phi) = \frac{d^2 + b^2 - x^2 - y^2}{2db}$ and you can find $\theta + \phi$ by taking the $\arccos$ of both sides.

Now you know the value of $\theta + \phi$, you can do the same trick but subtract $y^2$ instead of add it this time. So

$x^2 - y^2 = d^2 - b^2 - 2db(\cos(\theta - \phi))$ (skipping some of the working because it is the same as before.

This time, you get

$\cos(\theta - \phi) = \frac{d^2 - b^2 - x^2 + y^2}{2db}$ and so you can find $\theta - \phi$ by taking the $\arccos$ of both sides.

Now you know the value of both $\theta + \phi$ and $\theta - \phi$. Let

$A = \theta + \phi$

$B = \theta - \phi$

Then $\theta = \frac{A+B}{2}$ and $\phi = \frac{A-B}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for responding ♥ , but I mistyped the equations you used, if you have the time can you adjust your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested start too long for a comment.

The third and fourth equations have the form

$$
x = r\cos \sigma + s \sin \tau
$$
$$
y = r\sin \sigma + s \cos \tau
$$
with $x$, $y$, $r$ and $s$ known since computable from known things.

I *think* you can solve these for the angles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ by squaring each and playing with $\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1$ and  the addition formula for $\sin$.

Then you can use $\sigma$ and $\tau$   to calculate $\alpha$ and $\theta$.